# Remove custom post type slug from URL

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

Haven't found a useful answer for this.  I am aware of the conflict issues and all the problems this may cause, I'm curious if it's POSSIBLE not SUGGESTED.  This will require WP rewrites, I know this much.

Basically, let's say we have a CPT of "events".  I want to have a single event's page have the URL http://domain.com/single-event-name and NOT http://domain.com/events/single-event-name.  Any ideas on how to go about it?

Comment: Always wanted to find out about that, never thought of asking the question. Thanks!

Comment: @robbennet in 2015 there still doesn't seem to be a legit way to do this with style.

Answer (score 9):

That's how you can do first part of the job - get rid o CPT slug in post link (eg. news post type).

```
function df_custom_post_type_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {  

    $post = get_post($id);  

    if ( is_wp_error($post) || 'news' != $post->post_type || empty($post->post_name) )  
        return $post_link;  

    return home_url(user_trailingslashit( "$post->post_name" ));  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'df_custom_post_type_link' , 10, 2 );
```

Now there should go a a rewrite rules for 'news', because you will get a 404 error.

Add the rewrite rule like this:

```
function df_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*?)$', 'index.php?news=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'df_custom_rewrite_rule');
```

Then we'll need to flush rewrite rules, so go to Settings - Permalinks and save changes.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding rewrite rules on init.  You should just add your rule to the current rules.

Comment: @Chris_O Can you elaborate? How would one add the rule to the current rules?

Comment: After adding this code, all of my pages having URLS as **http://example.com/about-us** stopped working ? Any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this plugin( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/ ) for removing the slug, but it will only work if the permalink structure is "/%postname%/

Comment: Exactly this plugin is awesome! I'm an experienced user of this plugin and I totally recommend it! 

here's the link of the plugin's site which explain it in depth http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/

Comment: This is a nice Plugin, and has exactly the feature I was looking for. @bartosz solution is to one CPT specifically, although you too get the general idea from it. After digging into this Plugin it's all clear now, thank you!

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to be in the Wordpress repository anymore. However you can use this plugin instead.... [https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-cpt-base/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-cpt-base/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function register_cpt_type() {
    register_post_type('cpt', array(
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "/cpt", "with_front" => false),
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'register_cpt_type')

function cpt_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*?)$', 'index.php?cpt=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('after_theme_setup', 'cpt_rewrite_rule');
```

flush/recycle url rewrites, then edit .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^cpt/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always hook into "parse_request" to perform a check to see if a custom type with the name requested exists and then modify the query_vars appropriately. You'll need something along the lines of @Bartosz's response to generate the permalink in addition:

```
 add_filter('parse_request', "t21_parse_request" , 1, 1);

 function t21_parse_request($wpobj)
 {
      $query_vars = $wpobj->query_vars;
      $slug = $query_vars['pagename'];

      $posts = get_posts(array(
           "post_type" => "event",
           "post_name" => $slug
      ));

      if($posts)
      {
           //we know your "event" entry exists so we now amend the query_vars
           //first unset the 'page' and 'pagename'
           unset($query_vars['page']);
           unset($query_vars['pagename']);

           //now rebuild the query_vars
           $query_vars['post_type'] = "event"; //CPT name
           $query_vars['name'] = $slug;
           $query_vars['event'] = $slug; //again - this constructs the "event=myevent" query string
      }
      else
      {
           //just return $wpobj since we know that there is no "event"
           return $wpobj;
      }
 }
```

This does assume however that you won't have any post names with the same name as a postname otherwise, the post will never appear as it matches with an event type first.